# Android TextView with multiline and "android:ellipsize = middle"

Tags: android, textview

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/food_item_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:ellipsize="middle"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textColor="@color/food_cell_text"
        android:text=""Cured beef salad with rocket lettuce,cherry tomato & grana padano""/>
```

But the text in the TextView do not have ellipsis in the middle as if the 
attributes is not useless，When I change 
`android:ellipsize="end"`, The text have ellipsis in the end. Why? And how can I have ellipsis in the middle?

Comment: I can not understand what you want please add screen shot

Comment: do you want to set your text in the center?

Comment: for test case add `android:singleLine="true" ` instead of `android:maxLines="2"`

Comment: plz post screnshot  what you exactly want in Textview?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Yeah, I know the content will have  ellipsis in the middle when using `androidLsingleLine="true"`. But I just want the TextView with mutiline  and the ellipsis in the middle

Comment: @MehrozMunir no, I want the text have ellipsis in the middle not the text in the center.

Comment: @David.Cui any solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`android:ellipsize="middle"` doesn't seem to work with multiple lines on Android 4.0 and later. you could try the following which will work, however you only have the one line. Add the following to your textview.

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

Comment: oh ，really？ Is “android:ellipsize="middle" doesn't seem to work with multiple lines on Android 4.0 and later.” true？

Comment: Even with single line it's broken on Android 11. Just a shame a company like Google is not capable of getting stuff like this fixed…

Answer (score 0):

[image]try this code:

```
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/food_item_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txt"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    android:ellipsize="middle"
    android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:text="Cured beef salad with rocket lettuce,cherry tomato , grana padano"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="17sp" />
```

this is screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code, its working :

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/food_item_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="middle"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textColor="@color/food_cell_text"
        android:text=""Cured beef salad with rocket lettuce,cherry tomato & grana padano""/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If setMaxLines(int) has been used to set two or more lines, only TextUtils.TruncateAt.END and TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE are supported (other ellipsizing types will not do anything).
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:ellipsize

if you want to use textview with 2 lines and ellipsize=middle 
you can divide your text in half and to do use it

```
      <TextView
            android:id="@+id/food_item_name_first_line"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:text="Cured beef salad with rocket "/>
       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/food_item_name_second_line"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:text="lettuce,cherry tomato & grana padano"/>
```

[it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfmYF.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Try this,

```
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/food_item_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:ellipsize="middle"
        android:layout_margin="50dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:textColor="@color/keyBagroung"
        android:text="@string/Curved"/>
```

Try to use string in Strings.xml file,
Like this

```
 <string name="Curved">Cured beef salad with rocket lettuce,cherry tomato &amp; grana padano</string>
```

because special characters are not allowed in xml file.

Comment: No no,That is not my question... In screen shot I want to The TextView have ellipsis in the middle when the TextView have definite width and the content will exceed the width。