# TextView with ellipsize middle casues "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" Exception

Tags: android, textview

**Edited:**

I am getting `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:` **Exception** for a TextView with ellipsize `middle`. Here is my TextView

```
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:ellipsize="middle"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="27dp"
        android:text="123456 123 1234567890123456"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
```

I have experimented with this **Exception** and its causing for `calculateEllipsis()` method with this given margin, padding,textSize and singleLine.

Here is **CrashLog**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=125; index=-1
        at android.text.StaticLayout.calculateEllipsis(StaticLayout.java:786)
        at android.text.StaticLayout.out(StaticLayout.java:705)
        at android.text.StaticLayout.generate(StaticLayout.java:410)
        at android.text.StaticLayout.<init>(StaticLayout.java:140)
        at android.widget.TextView.makeSingleLayout(TextView.java:6068)
        at android.widget.TextView.makeNewLayout(TextView.java:5925)
        at android.widget.TextView.onMeasure(TextView.java:6282)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4919)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1411)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:698)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:681)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4919)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4919)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1411)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:698)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4919)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4919)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1411)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:698)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4919)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2200)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2165)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1249)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1443)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1139)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4872)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:776)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:579)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:548)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:762)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is some scenario where i am not getting **Exception**

1. If i remove the last character( set text "123456 123 123456789012345" removed '6' from last ) then i don't get Exception
2. If i set textSize **14sp** then i don't get any Exception
3. IF i set ellipsize="end" it worked fine.
4. Its working fine in high resolution devices with same TextView properties.

I think making **ellipsize middle** with the large last word "1234567890123456" (16 character) caused This Exception.

Here is my device Specification:

1. Model: **HUAWEI Y320-U30**
2. Android **Version: 4.2.2**

Can anyone explain whats wrong with `calculateEllipsis()` method with this scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this it may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739721/android-ellipsise-meaning-of-the-options

Comment: Could you show the `calculateEllipsis` method ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37387233/8089770

Comment: @KeLiuyue please check the 3rd line of the log i posted. Its library method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got my answer. It's a bug for pre lolipop device if i use both `android:ellipsize="middle"` and `android:maxLines="1"` . The solution is to use `android:singleLine="true"`. This prevent my crash. Here is the [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33868) . You can also check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18564198/1292557)